# A table with 3 columns and many rows has many pictures!

Tags: tables, longtable

I want to draw a table with 3 `columns` and many rows which has many picture on it! Pictures have fixed `height` and `width`, and in every row I have a formula with two pictures. I want to break the table at the end of the page and used below code but it has some errors. I appreciate your hints and some better ways for doing this.

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
\parbox[t]{0.3\textwidth}
{\vspace{-3cm}
\left 
\begin{eqnarray}
F=z-\frac{1}{2}z^2\\
h=z\\
g=\frac{1}{2}z^2\\
f=z+\frac{1}{2}\overline{z}^2
\end{eqnarray}
\right.
}
&\parbox[b]{0.3\textwidth}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Fig10_1.png}}
&\parbox[t]{0.3\textwidth}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Fig10_2.png}}
\\\hline 
\end{tabular}\\
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to put some deliminator after `\left` and `\left` and `\right` require math mode; you cannot use `eqnarray` in this table (unless you put it into a minipage), and you should anyway switch to `align`; and if you really want help, provide an MWE, please.

Comment: @marmot Thanks. What deliminator may I use?

Comment: Brackets or . ... but please try an MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as example of *mwe* (which also solve your problem, i hope):

- it start with `\documentclass{...}`
- continue with preamble, where are loaded only to problem related package
- body of document star by `\begin{document}` followed with your table and ending with `\end{document}`

please, always provide minimal working example (*mwe*). by it you help us to help you. it is not fun write from scratch missing code, actually without it waste our spare time i which we may be able to help someone other :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|C|C|C|}
    \hline
$
\begin{cases}
  F=z-\frac{1}{2}z^2,   &   \\
  g=\frac{1}{2}z^2,     &   \\
  f=z+\frac{1}{2}\overline{z}^2&
\end{cases}
$
    &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=c,margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt]{example-image-a}
        &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image-b}    \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

from above code follows:

- for table environment is handy to use `tabularx` environment
- for horizontal centering of cell content is define new column type `C`
- for vertical `centering is used macro`valign`from package`adjustbox`(this package also call package`graphicx`, from where are used demo images`example-image-a`and`example-image-b`
- for math is used `cases` environment from `amsmath` (simpler than your construct)

**your problem:**

partial is solved by above *mwe*, however for multi page long table i suggest to use `ltablex` package, which merge features of `longtable` and `tabularx`. in this case it shold be changed to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{ltablex} % new package
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{$}C<{$}|C|C|} %  for shorter code in first column, which now is in math mode
    \hline
\begin{cases}
  F=z-\frac{1}{2}z^2,   &   \\
  g=\frac{1}{2}z^2,     &   \\
  f=z+\frac{1}{2}\overline{z}^2&
\end{cases}
    &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=c,margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt]{example-image-a}
        &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image-b}    \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```